# NativeScript RTL support

Tags: nativescript

My app can have only one language, and it should be aligned RTL.
Currently when I run my app with `tns preview` the `ActionBar` labels appears in the left (instead of the right) and so on with any other widget.

I have found some localization plugins but not sure I need them for my case - since I have only one language and text direction.

I have been through all GitHub issues related to RTL but I'm still not sure how to work it out. Any idea how I can force my app and change the layout for RTL language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the layout direction to RTL at runtime, this would not only update ActionBar but any layout in app will be forced for RTL.

```
import * as app from 'tns-core-modules/application';

app.android.addEventListener(app.AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, (event: app.AndroidActivityEventData) => {
   event.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
});
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=KqTQXe)

Comment: Where do you import `android.` from?

Comment: You don't import it, its native package available at runtime. Refer the Playground sample, you can use `declare var android` to avoid Typescript errors.

Comment: Thanks. It worked - but it totally screwed the nativescript views. It look like the RTL support is lacking

Comment: You are only forcing the layouts to follow RTL. That's the expected behavior, you must have built your layouts for LTR, it will completely switch when you enable RTL.

Comment: @MuhammadAdil I don't see any issues while running same code in latest Playground. If you have issues, share the updated Playground sample.

Comment: @Manoj Can you show me the playground where you run the code, where you added this code in angular project.

Comment: You could do add this code to `main.ts`, make sure you do the platform check.